# android dev - TabBar example with 3 fragments - error when clicking on another tab item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to learn more about fragments ( coding) , so I cloned the standard TabBar project and tried to replace the unique Dummy fragment with 3 different fragments...
The initial Action Bar is displayed correctly , but when I click on another tab ( 2nd or 3rd) I get a NullPointer Exception :

```
12-20 17:46:19.729: E/Trace(5698): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:389)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
at com.example.actionbar.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:62)
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:570)
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1067)
at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:489)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The only change I wrote in the MainActivity is related to the Fragment getItem()

```
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragment fragment1 = new DummySection1Fragment();
            args.putInt(DummySection1Fragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment1.setArguments(args);
            return fragment1;
        case 1:
            Fragment fragment2 = new DummySection2Fragment();
            args.putInt(DummySection2Fragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment2.setArguments(args);
            return fragment2;
        case 3:
            Fragment fragment3 = new DummySection3Fragment();
            args.putInt(DummySection3Fragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
            fragment3.setArguments(args);
            return fragment3;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

No change to the callbacks

```
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

and I have created 3 DummySectionFragment to replace the unique one in the standard :

```
    public static class DummySection1Fragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section1_number";

    public DummySection1Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy1,container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class DummySection2Fragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section2_number";

    public DummySection2Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy2,container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class DummySection3Fragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section3_number";

    public DummySection3Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy3,container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I guess I am missing something important but I cannot find where ...
thanks for your feedback

don't worry about the E/Trace open error, I'll post another question about it ...

Comment: you have detach the fragment in `onTabUnselected`

Comment: I did it ... but error still in tabSelected ... it seems I need to redesign the all bunch...
to detach it I used :
  int id = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
  // FragmentPagerAdapter are auto-tagged when they're instantiated
  android.app.Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":"+id);
  fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running , after reading the answer of post  [Lost in comprehension Fragments/Tabs + ActionBar + swipe (ICS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452544/lost-in-comprehension-fragments-tabs-actionbar-swipe-ics)

should have onlt one dummy¨section and switch inside the onCreateView of the dummy_section.java